# does it possible to save Db file with application and not by adding in from itunes

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, sqlite

I want the application which work online as well as offline example `WhatsApp`. For that i have to sync data from web service then store it in sqlite db file. 
And I want that whoever installs this application would have a slot for automatic saving data in database file. Do I have to add db file from iTunes?

I don't want to use core data concept.
Is it possible it will be there in with application?

Like in Android there is something called cache memory where db file is stored so there is any sort of provision for it in ios?

```
+(int)insert_In_AdverImage:(NSString *)strid ImageName:(NSString *)strimg Isshow:(NSString *)strshow LastUpdateId:(NSString *)date isdelete:(NSString *)isdelete Sortorder:(int)sortOrder{
sqlite3 *database;
int retValue = 0;
if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
    NSString *tempSQL = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO ADVERIMAGE(advId ,advimg ,isshow ,LastUpdateId ,IsDelete  ,SortorderId ) VALUES ('%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', '%d')", strid, strimg, strshow, date, isdelete, sortOrder];
    const char *sqlStatement = [tempSQL cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL);
    sqlite3_step(compiledStatement);
    retValue = (int)sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database);
    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
}
sqlite3_close(database);
return retValue;
```

}

works well. But still the db file in app bundle is empty.i got it that whenever we insert something it will be inserted in document and if we have to see the inserted data we have to get it from document

Thanks in advance

Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Possible.

You can store SQlite DB in your applications's Document Directory. You need to write your own Query to Open DB, Insert Data, Retrieve Data from DB.

Check out following tutorial for your requirement : http://www.appcoda.com/sqlite-database-ios-app-tutorial/

Hope it helps.

Following function is used to Insert :

```
    NSArray *docsDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *docPath = [docsDirectory objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *databasePath = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Database.sqlite"];

    sqlite3 *dbHandler;

    const char *dbPath = [databasePath UTF8String];

    sqlite3_stmt *sqlStmt;

    if(sqlite3_open(dbPath, &dbHandler) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(dbHandler, [queryString UTF8String], -1, &sqlStmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            if (sqlite3_step(sqlStmt) == SQLITE_DONE)
            {
                NSLog(@"Data Inserted");
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"Not inserted");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Failed to Insert data -InsertDataFunc");
        }

     sqlite3_close(dbHandler);
 }
```

Comment: You need to Open DB first. followed by Insert query needs to processed. You check with the Query and arguments you're passing and elaborate more about the error you're getting

Comment: Can you share the Insert functionality code ? So that i can found out the error.

Comment: now the problem is when i upload the application to appstore and user uses it then data will be stores or they have to add externally

Comment: did it still the db file is null. and it should be null because we have inserted by creating a copy from appbundle to documents.do read the edited question.and thanx @Balaji Ramakrishnan